# Border radius on focus for image inside anchor tag

Tags: html, css, focus, outline, border-radius

I have this CSS:

```
.sky:focus {border-radius: 25px; border: #000 solid 1px; outline: none}
```

& this HTML:

```
<a class='sky' href='#'><img src='cloud.jpg'></a>
```

I wished a 25px border-radius on that **focus**, but it is not working. How to set border-radius on **focus** for the image inside an anchor tag?

Wished: [image: Wished One]

Get: [image: Get One]

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Set your a tag to display: block, it should works

Comment: It's now https://prnt.sc/t6ardt :(

Comment: Set it to display: inline-block so, so the a tag take the content of the image

Comment: By default, a tag are display inline. That's why you get strange border. Inspect the a tag with your inspector without the display: inline-block; you will see that the a tag is strange and it is at the bottom of the image

Comment: Thanks a lot Théo Benoit, you are amazing! Solved by:    .sky:focus {border-radius: 25px; border: #000 solid 1px; outline: none; display: inline-block;}
    img {border-radius: 25px;}

Comment: Or by this one: .b2:focus {border-radius: 25px; border: #000 solid 1px; outline: none; display: inline-block;padding:1px;}

Answer (score 2):

Solved by this, thank you Théo Benoit!

```
.sky:focus {background-color:#fff; border-radius: 5px; border: #000 solid 1px; display: inline-block; padding:2px;}
```